# How do I install the firmware on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, firmware

I have a Dell Latitude D610 and whenever I try to connect to wifi, it says missing firmware. When I open my additional drives icon, nothing is there. I have rebooted many times. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try install the [linux-firmware-nonfree [image: Install linux-firmware-nonfree]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-firmware-nonfree) package. Use your favourite package manager, or use the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

The package includes some firmware, such as Broadcom wireless card firmware binaries. You can see the list here: [Launchpad page about the linux-firmware-nonfree package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-nonfree).

Comment: This may also be `firmware-linux-free` if you're running Debian (I recognize this is AskUbuntu, not AskDebian).

Answer (score 2):

first enable non-free debian packages by editing 
**/etc/apt/sources.list** and adding contrib and non-free to the line

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main
```

so it becomes

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

and also add these lines:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

now run

```
apt-get update
```

then you can look at firmware packages you might want by typing

```
apt-file --package-only search /lib/firmware/
```

and finally run

```
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

and any other packages you think you need

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have an internet connection on the machine you're working on, which might happen with this kind of problem, you can download the firmware package with another machine, transfer to the machine without connection and install it using the Ubuntu software center (right click on the deb file and select application).